# str_replace on a posted form

Tags: php, string, forms, validation

i want to replace any " ' " that people post on my form with nothing as it's causing errors down the line at the moment i've tried this

```
$visit = str_replace("","'",$this->input->post('visit_type'));
```

This Changes nothing, is their an easier way around this?

Bare in mind im just a humble apprentice developer. Don't get too technical.

Comment: Read up on SQL injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

It's a safety measure. You don't want to replace the quotes but 'escape' them.

Comment: str_replace("'","",$this->input->post('visit_type'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `htmlspecialchars` and `addslashes` that *convert special characters to HTML entities* and *quote string with slashes* but if you want to use str_replace, the correct usage is `$visit = str_replace("'","",$this->input->post('visit_type'));`

The first paramater is the search value and the second the replacement value that replaces found search values

Answer (score 1):

Swap your parameters around:

`$visit = str_replace("'","",$this->input->post('visit_type'));`

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace("'","",$this->input->post('visit_type'));`

please read the documentation on str_replace..

https://www.php.net/str_replace